# Bootstap responsive image on top of another image

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm creating a Santa letter writing website and I'm trying to get a graphic of Santa to look like it is riding on top of the snow. The issue is I cannot seem to get it to work responsively. For reference below is a mockup image of how I would like the Santa graphic placed with everything else I have. How can I make this work?

Comment: Post your [mcve] in your question please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The container needed bit restructuring to make it work. On the image set following classes `img-fluid w-50 h-50 align-self-end`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" referrerpolicy="no-referrer">

<head referrerpolicy="no-referrer">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- remove following in production-->
  <meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer">
  <title>Reindeer Express</title>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <!-- link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.2/jspdf.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/1463370ce3.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <style>
    .bg-img {

      background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/9L54Zdw.png");
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;

      position: relative;
    }

    .custom-shape-divider-bottom-1637548946 {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
      line-height: 0;
      transform: rotate(180deg);
    }

    .custom-shape-divider-bottom-1637548946 svg {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      width: calc(100% + 1.3px);
      height: 70px;
    }

    .custom-shape-divider-bottom-1637548946 .shape-fill {
      fill: #FFFFFF;
    }

    #stop-btn {
      display: none;
    }


    #how-to-mail {
      display: none;
    }

    #hidden-template {
      display: none;
    }

    .img-anim {
      transform-origin: 25% 75%;
      animation: ride 2s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate;
    }

    @keyframes ride {
      0% {
        transform: rotateZ(356deg);
      }

      100% {
        transform: rotateZ(359deg);
      }

    }

  </style>
</head>

<body onload=display_countdown; referrerpolicy="no-referrer">
  <div class="bg-img">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-sm">
      <div class="container-fluid position-relative">
        <a class="navbar-brand position-absolute fixed-top" style="left:12px" href="#">
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/vavioW9.png" alt="" width="24" height="29"
            class="d-inline-block align-text-top">
          Reindeer Express
        </a>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse flex-grow-0 mx-auto">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#"><u>Home</u></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#"><u>Nav Item</u></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item ">
              <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#"><u>Nav Item</u></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container col-xxl-8 px-4 py-5">
      <div class="d-sm-flex justify-content-between">
        <img class="img-fluid w-50 h-50 align-self-end img-anim" src="https://i.imgur.com/4n4uujr.png">
        <div class="col flex-lg-row-reverse align-items-center g-5 p-5">
          <div class="col-10">
            <h1 class="fw-bold lh-1 mb-3 text-white">Reindeer Express</h1>
            <p class="lead text-white" id="welcome">Welcome Friends to the Reindeer Express! Have you ever wanted to
              write
              a letter
              to Santa Clause? Well now you can! Fill out the form below to let Santa know what you would like for
              Christmas!
              But that is not all! You can also download a copy of your letter once you send it! How cool is that?</p>
          </div>
          <div class="">
            <h1 class="text-white" id="countdown_days"></h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-shape-divider-bottom-1637548946">
      <svg data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1200 120" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <path
          d="M0,0V46.29c47.79,22.2,103.59,32.17,158,28,70.36-5.37,136.33-33.31,206.8-37.5C438.64,32.43,512.34,53.67,583,72.05c69.27,18,138.3,24.88,209.4,13.08,36.15-6,69.85-17.84,104.45-29.34C989.49,25,1113-14.29,1200,52.47V0Z"
          opacity=".25" class="shape-fill"></path>
        <path
          d="M0,0V15.81C13,36.92,27.64,56.86,47.69,72.05,99.41,111.27,165,111,224.58,91.58c31.15-10.15,60.09-26.07,89.67-39.8,40.92-19,84.73-46,130.83-49.67,36.26-2.85,70.9,9.42,98.6,31.56,31.77,25.39,62.32,62,103.63,73,40.44,10.79,81.35-6.69,119.13-24.28s75.16-39,116.92-43.05c59.73-5.85,113.28,22.88,168.9,38.84,30.2,8.66,59,6.17,87.09-7.5,22.43-10.89,48-26.93,60.65-49.24V0Z"
          opacity=".5" class="shape-fill"></path>
        <path
          d="M0,0V5.63C149.93,59,314.09,71.32,475.83,42.57c43-7.64,84.23-20.12,127.61-26.46,59-8.63,112.48,12.24,165.56,35.4C827.93,77.22,886,95.24,951.2,90c86.53-7,172.46-45.71,248.8-84.81V0Z"
          class="shape-fill"></path>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
  <section id="form-area" class="py-3">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row py-5">
        <div class="col text-center">
          <h2>Write a letter to Santa</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-12 ">

          <img class="img-fluid d-block mx-auto w-75" src="https://i.imgur.com/ZeukS4C.png"
            alt="santa standing by a reindeer">

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-12">
          <form id="form" onsubmit="handleSubmit(event)">

            <div class="mb-3 form-floating">
              <input type="email" placeholder="ex: parent@mail.com" class="form-control" id="parentEmail"
                oninput="handleChange(event)" required>
              <label for="parentEmail" class="form-label">Parent's Email Address</label>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
                <div class="form-floating mb-3 ">
                  <input type="text" placeholder="ex: Sally Smith" class="form-control" id="name"
                    oninput="handleChange(event)" required>
                  <label for="name" class="form-label">Name</label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                <div class="form-floating mb-3 ">
                  <input type="number" placeholder="3" class="form-control" id="age" oninput="handleChange(event)"
                    required min="0" max="150">
                  <label for="age" class="form-label">Age</label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
                <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                  <select class="form-select" id="gender" aria-label="select gender" oninput="handleChange(event)"
                    required>
                    <option>Pick boy or girl</option>
                    <option value="boy">Boy</option>
                    <option value="girl">Girl</option>
                  </select>
                  <label for="gender" class="form-label">Gender</label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                  <select class="form-select" id="behavior" aria-label="select naughty or nice"
                    oninput="handleChange(event)" required>
                    <option>Select option</option>
                    <option value="nice">Nice</option>
                    <option value="naughty">Naughty</option>
                    <option value="okay">Okay</option>
                  </select>
                  <label for="behavior" class="form-label">Behavior</label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="wishlistOne" class="form-label">Name three things you would like for Christmas:</label>
              <input type="text" placeholder="1." class="form-control" id="wishlistOne" oninput="handleChange(event)"
                required>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
              <input type="text" placeholder="2." class="form-control" id="wishlistTwo" oninput="handleChange(event)"
                required>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
              <input type="text" placeholder="3." class="form-control" id="wishlistThree" oninput="handleChange(event)"
                required>
            </div>

            <div class="mb-3 form-floating">
              <textarea class="form-control textbox" id="message" oninput="handleChange(event)" rows="10"
                required></textarea>
              <label for="message" class="form-label">Write a message for Santa</label>

              <div class="row mt-1">
                <div class="col">
                  <p id="instructions" class="text-muted"></p>
                </div>
                <div class="col d-flex flex-row-reverse">
                  <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" id="start-btn">
                    <i class="fas fa-microphone"></i>
                    Start Voice to Text
                  </button>
                  <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" id="stop-btn">
                    <i class="fas fa-microphone-slash"></i>
                    End Voice to Text
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-12">
              <button id="send-letter-btn" class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="submit">
                <i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i> Submit
              </button>
            </div>

          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="how-to-mail" class="py-3">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col text-center">
          <h3>How to mail your letter</h3>
          <p class="fw-light">Instructions from the <a href="https://about.usps.com/holidaynews/">USPS</a></p>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col mail-instructions">
          <p>
            <span class="number">1. </span>Print downloaded PDF with your letter
          </p>
          <p>
            <span class="number">2. </span>Place letter in envelope
          </p>
          <p>
            <span class="number">3. </span>Address letter to "Santa Claus, North Pole"
          </p>
          <p>
            <span class="number">4. </span>Place First-Class Mail stamp to envelope
          </p>
          <p>
            <span class="number">5. </span>Have parent mail your letter!
            <br>
            <small class="fw-light">Additional instructions for <a
                href="https://about.usps.com/holidaynews/letters-from-santa.htm">parents</a></small>

          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </section>
  <footer class="py-5 bg-light">
    <p>footer</p>
  </footer>

  <!-- hidden template goes here -->
  <div id="hidden-template">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <p id="letter-name"></p>
          <p id="letter-age"></p>
          <p id="letter-gender"></p>
          <p id="letter-behavior"></p>
          <p id="letter-wishlist-one"></p>
          <p id="letter-wishlist-two"></p>
          <p id="letter-wishlist-three"></p>
          <p id="letter-message"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="elementH"></div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
  <script src="./js/form.js"></script>
  <script src="./js/speech.js"></script>
  <script>
    var display_countdown = setInterval(function () {
      countdown();
    }, 10)

    function countdown() {
      var currentDate = new Date();
      var christmasDate = new Date("12/25/2021 12:00:00");
      var timeLeft = christmasDate.getTime() - currentDate.getTime();
      var days_Left = Math.round(timeLeft / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      if (currentDate.getTime() !== christmasDate.getTime()) {
        days_Left - 1;
        document.getElementById('countdown_days').innerHTML = "Christmas is in " + days_Left + " Days!";
      } else {
        document.getElementById('countdown_days').innerHTML = "MERRY CHRISTMAS!";
      }
      display_countdown;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Note:** In order to make your code work in my environment I had to made some changes. Like putting entire style.css in `<style>` tag, added meta referer tag, added bootstrap cdn link. Remove the animation if you don't like it.

Compress the background image it's too big 1.77mb. Convert it to jpg, because the png is not transparent.

Comment: That does look much better with the smaller dimensions on the image.

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

That should work just great if you add `img-fluid` to the image Class.

```
 <img src="https://i.imgur.com/4n4uujr.png" class="img-fluid">
```